# ES6 Class: access to 'this' with 'addEventListener' applied on method

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, dom-events

In this es6 script, the click event don't works because `sayHello` method is called with `this.elm` (`<div>`) as `this`.

how to associate a event to a method without loose the scope?

```
class player{
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.elm = document.createElement('div');
    this.elm.addEventListener('click', this.sayHello);
  }
  sayHello() {
    console.log(this.name + ' say: "hello!"'); // 'undefined say 'hello!"';
  }
  kill() {
    console.log(`RIP ${this.name} :'(`); 
    this.elm.addClass('dead');
    this.elm.removeEventListener('click', this.sayHello);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 128):

This is a general JS issue, but the core of it is that

```
this.elm.addEventListener('click', this.sayHello);
```

is no different than

```
var fn = this.sayHello;
this.elm.addEventListener('click', fn);
```

You are passing a function as the event handler, but have not ensured that when `fn` is called that `this` will be set to your desired value. The easiest way to do this in ES5 would be

```
this.elm.addEventListener('click', this.sayHello.bind(this));
```

or in ES6, using an arrow function:

```
this.elm.addEventListener('click', evt => this.sayHello(evt));
```

Note however that both of these solutions will break your (already slightly broken) logic in `kill` because

```
this.elm.removeEventListener('click', /* what? */);
```

You don't have any reference to the function that you attached anymore, so you have no way of removing the event handler.

I'd suggest two options:

```
// Create a new function that is bound, and give it a new name
// so that the 'this.sayHello()' call still works.
this.boundSayHello = evt => this.sayHello(evt);
this.elm.addEventListener('click', this.boundSayHello);
this.elm.removeEventListener('click', this.boundSayHello);
```

or

```
// Bind the function with the same name and use `.bind` instead of the
// arrow function option.
this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
this.elm.addEventListener('click', this.sayHello);
this.elm.removeEventListener('click', this.sayHello);
```

Comment: thank, it's what I use, but each object need to have a object pointing on each binded function needed as callback http://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/yNVVxV/?editors=001

Comment: Great! I prefer the first solution. First I tried .bind(this) but then it failed when trying to get other variables inside the this scope because I was inside an ES6 class.

Comment: Ah so `canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', pad_mouseDown, false);` in ES6 class style will be `this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', evt=> this.pad_mouseDown(evt), false);`