# es6 classes and "this" with event handlers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

playing around with some es6 and ran into an issue i'm not sure how to solve. consider the following

```
class Foo {
 constructor ( ) {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.watch);
 }

 watch ( ) {
   console.log(this);
 }
}
```

Inside of `watch`, `this` is the `window` object, as expected. But how do i refer to `Foo`? Currently I get around this with bind `this.watch.bind(this)` but i'd love to know if there is a more "proper" ES6 way to get this going.

Comment: I'd typically have a 'var self = this' just inside Foo, but it feels equally as nasty. But remember, JavaScript isn't an OO language.

Comment: The article [ECMAScript 6: automatically binding extracted methods](http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/auto-binding.html) presents 2 solutions.

Comment: Try using a fat arrow function for watch: `watch() {() => {console.log(this)} }`

Comment: @OriDrori proxies have only been implemented in recent FF and MS Edge and are not (and I would think, could not) polyfilled by transpilers.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: They are called "arrow functions", not "fat arrow functions".

Comment: @FelixKling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @BrianGlaz: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions ... "fat arrow function" comes from CoffeeScript, but it's not an *official* term in JavaScript. Makes sense, since there is no "thin arrow function".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use arrow function.

> An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a
>   shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **lexically binds
>   the this value**.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.watch());
```

Comment: this looks the nicest IMO. thanks for the feedback!

Comment: What about `removeEventListener`?! Use `bind(this)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446622/es6-acces-to-this-with-addeventlistener-applied-on-method for details.

Comment: Sadly, you have to send in each parameter manually if you do this. Oh well ..

Answer (score 1):

The `class` keyword is just a syntatic sugar for the known javascript prototype inheritance chain. The way the this attribution mechanism works is the same. Just keep thinking about the class as the good old function what works with this, so it can be attributed to the one that used the `new` keyword.

E6 comes with lots of new keywords to make object oriented javascript more familiar. I'm happy with that but we all must remember that the fundamental parts are still the same, just now with some shadows for newcomers :D

Ps:
Given that you know how `this` is defined in Javascript, you can use it without an alias, like `self` or something like that, despite that beeing a common practice.