# trouble removing EventListeners from the listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In my JS module I have a function that adds a couple event listeners

```
clickCatcher.addEventListener("click", this.clickCatcherFunction);
window.addEventListener('resize', this.clickCatcherFunction);
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.clickCatcherFunction);
```

and the function clickCatcherFunction is called, all good so far.  Now it's time to remove all the event listeners if one of them triggered.

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.clickCatcherFunction);
```

No errors, but the event listeners are still active. How do I access the same function that I passed in? Inside the listener function, this.someOtherFunc also fails.  What's the scope of this listener, has it changed?

Edit. Adding more for context:

```
export default class Hints {

    constructor(){
        //ref for adding and removing
        this.clickCatcherFunction = this.clickCatcherFunction.bind(this);

        //add invisible top div to catch click and remove hint, 
        const clickCatcher = document.createElement("div"); 
        clickCatcher.id = "clickCatcher";
        document.body.appendChild(clickCatcher);
        clickCatcher.addEventListener('click', this.clickCatcherFunction);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.clickCatcherFunction);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.clickCatcherFunction);
    }

    clickCatcherFunction() {
        //clickCatcher gets deleted from the dom
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.clickCatcherFunction);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.clickCatcherFunction);
    }
}


//in the JS that imported Hints.JS
import Hints from "../Hints.js"
let hint = new Hints();
```

Adding solution into constructor.

Comment: if `clickCatcherFunction()` is global it would work; but only if the all the add and remove calls also happen in the global context.

Comment: use the `that=this` trick, or bind() your callback to get the right refs.

Comment: Duplicate of [es6 classes and "this" with event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893600/es6-classes-and-this-with-event-handlers) (unfortunately already broke my Mjölnir on previous version of the question..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.removeEventListener` for every call you've made in adding it.

So from your code:

```
clickCatcher.removeEventListener('click', this.clickCatcherFunction);
window.removeEventListener('resize', this.clickCatcherFunction);
document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.clickCatcherFunction);
```

Mind, I'd be careful about pointing to `this` the way you are. `this` will be the enclosing object of the context you're calling is. Which may not be what you want.

Based on your edit:

`document.addEventListener('keydown', this.clickCatcherFunction.bind(this));`

Will help.

Comment: using .bind(this) with addEventListener enabled that function to reference other functions with this.other.  But didn't remove the eventlisteners from window or document.  But if I put a this.listener = this.listener.bind(this) in the constructor, I could use it to add and remove.

Comment: Yeah, because .bind returns a function.