# ES6 Execute a function on a click event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a small chunk of my code. The problem is about **this**. The code below "**this**" refers to **HomeView** class because I did this._changeLanguage.***bind(this)***. If I remove the **bind(this)** part then **this** refers to **li element** but then I cannot call **this._renderHTML()** method.

```
class HomeView extends BaseView{

    constructor(model){
        super(null, model);
    }

    _renderHTML(){
        this.$view.html(template(this.model));
        return this.$view;
    }

    _init(){
        this.$view.on("click", "#langs li", this._changeLanguage.bind(this));
    }

    _changeLanguage(){
        console.log($(this).data("lang"));
        this._renderHTML();
    }

}
```

What is the cleanest approach to run **_changeLanguage** method on a click event like this.

Comment: Just use `this.$view`?

Comment: I usually use the methods with arrow function, if using babel. [Example](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/#example)

Comment: See also [ES6 acces to 'this' with 'addEventListener' applied on method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30446622/3853934).

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to write your `_changeLanguage()` method as such:
    class HomeView extends BaseView {

```
    _changeLanguage = () => {
        console.log($(this).data("lang"));
        this._renderHTML();
    };
}
```

The fat-arrow syntax gives you implicit binding on `this`, so you can change your other code to:

```
_init(){
    this.$view.on("click", "#langs li", this._changeLanguage);
}
```

Therefore no more `bind()`... it's all implicit thanks to ES6.