# Function calls vs function references in event listeners

Tags: javascript

I was working on a very simple electron app, following a guide on Youtube and the teacher has me put an event listener on a button, like so:

```
button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    main.openWindow();
});
```

Standard stuff.  `main` is from using Electron's remote module to allow me to grab the exports object off the main js file that runs the electron.  `openWindow()` is the exported function and it opens an Electron window.  And it works.

I thought I'd make it tighter by doing this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', main.openWindow);
```

Except I get an error when I click on the button:

> Uncaught Error: No such module: atom_common_app

I'm not sure I understand the difference between the first snippet and the second.  The first uses an anonymous function that calls my exported function, the other gives the add event listener a reference to that function to use when the button is clicked on.  I don't understand why one works and the other does not.  What is the difference between the first snippet and the second?

Thanks

Comment: Simillar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298918/is-it-possible-to-call-a-class-method-with-addeventlistener

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446622/es6-class-access-to-this-with-addeventlistener-applied-on-method

Comment: **Bottom line:** In the first example, the **`this`** inside `openWindow` will be your `main` object. In the second it will be the DOM element that fired the event. Apparently `openWindow` uses `this` internally and it's expecting it to be `main`. In the first example, the function that get bound to the DOM element as its `this` value is the arrow function (that doesn't even have a `this` value anyway). In the second, it's `openWindow`

Comment: This might work: `button.addEventListener('click', main.openWindow.bind(main));`